# What does "take my own line" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The phrase came from a dialog between Mr. Cubitt and Mr. Sherlock Holmes in [The Dancing Men episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventure_of_the_Dancing_Men) of the TV Show [*The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes_(1984_TV_series)) Season 1.

From the [transcript](https://transcripts.thedealr.net/script.php/the-adventures-of-sherlock-holmes-1984-MXl/s1/e2):

> **Sherlock Holmes**: Don't you think, Mr. Cubitt, that your best plan would be to make a direct appeal to your wife, and ask her to share her secret with you?
>
> **Mr. Cubitt**: A promise is a promise, Mr. Holmes.  If Elsie wishes to tell me, then she will.  But I have no right to force a confidence. However, **I do feel entitled to take my own line**, and I will.

Comment: Although Mr Cubitt has asked Sherlock Holmes for advice, he feels entitled to do as he thinks right in dealing with the situation.  Oxford Dictionaries gives as one definition of _line_ 'A manner of doing or thinking about something'.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you.  That explains it.